# KeyError while using UnbalancedDataset package to over-sample a dataset (in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use [UnbalancedDataset](https://github.com/glemaitre/UnbalancedDataset) to over-sample my data. Following the sklearn convention, I have X,y as the feature matrix and target vector. These are of the pandas.core.frame.DataFrame type with a shape of (200000, 17) and (200000,) respectively.

I first split the data using the sklean's **train_test_split**. Then applied the **SMOTE** method to over-sample the training dataset which resulted in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1944             try:
-> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 1143

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-1c5830417b3f> in <module>()
      6 # 'SMOTE'
      7 SM = SMOTE(ratio=ratio, verbose=verbose, kind='regular')
----> 8 smx, smy = SM.fit_transform(Xtrain, ytrain)

C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\unbalanceddataset-0.1-py3.5.egg\unbalanced_dataset\unbalanced_dataset.py in fit_transform(self, x, y)
    274             return self.out_x, self.out_y, self.out_idx
    275         else:
--> 276             self.out_x, self.out_y = self.resample()
    277 
    278             return self.out_x, self.out_y

C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\unbalanceddataset-0.1-py3.5.egg\unbalanced_dataset\over_sampling.py in resample(self)
    358                                        step_size=1.0,
    359                                        random_state=self.rs,
--> 360                                        verbose=self.verbose)
    361 
    362             if self.verbose:

C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\unbalanceddataset-0.1-py3.5.egg\unbalanced_dataset\unbalanced_dataset.py in make_samples(x, nn_data, y_type, nn_num, n_samples, step_size, random_state, verbose)
    388 
    389             # Construct synthetic sample
--> 390             new[i] = x[row] - step * (x[row] - nn_data[nn_num[row, col]])
    391 
    392         # The returned target vector is simply a repetition of the

C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1996         else:
-> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1998 
   1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):

C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2002         # get column
   2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2005 
   2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1348         res = cache.get(item)
   1349         if res is None:
-> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
   1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1352             cache[item] = res

C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3288 
   3289             if not isnull(item):
-> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3291             else:
   3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:
-> 1947                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   1948 
   1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()

pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 1143
```

I got this error while all the under-sampling methods of the [UnbalancedDataset](https://github.com/glemaitre/UnbalancedDataset) on the same data worked fine. Any suggestions to handle the problem with oversampling?

**UPDATE:**

As glemaitre mentioned, to address the issue, the Pandas DataFrame needs to be converted to Numpy arrays. So, the following conversion would solve the problem:

```
Xc = Xtrain.as_matrix()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UnbalancedDataset expect numpy array. Try to plug that into the function and see if that works.

Cheers

Comment: glemaitre's answer is actually correct. I figured it out one day after I post the question. I should have mentioned it here too. I am going to edit my question and add more information to address the issue.